# google play won't allow my Australian credit card whilst in Indonesia

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Nextbook and have just set it up with my Australian credit card. I am living in Indonesia temporarily at the moment. Google play store won't allow me to purchase movies etc, stating 'unavailable in current location'. How do I fix this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a paypal and link the credit car to it. then use paypal as your payment option in the play store.